# How to set Canvas to Non-transparent Image?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a bitmap of size 400*100. Now i want to increase the bitmap size to 400*200 with empty white space on bottom. i tried the below code, but its creating transparent space, not white space.

=== My Code ===

```
// oldBitMap size are 400(width) and 100(height)

Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 200, oldBitMap.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

canvas.drawBitmap(oldBitMap, 0, 0, null);
```

Help Please....

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the first line to:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The only thing I can come up with is the original bitmap having a bad config.